# SetterBar Display using MatrixForm

Tags: syntax

I have

```
vAwGOptns = {
             {{0}, {0}},
             {{1}, {0}},
             {{0}, {1}},
             {{1}, {1}}
            };
```

and would like to select one of these vectors using SetterBar

```
SetterBar[Dynamic[vAwG], vAwGOptns]
```

which works fine. In the setter bar button text, it shows as "{{x},{y}}" but I was wondering if it was possible to force SetterBar to show the buttons as MatrixForm[{{x},{y}}] instead? Just so it looks nicer and is easier to read for vectors with more elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `val -> lbl` syntax for `SetterBar`:

```
SetterBar[Dynamic[vAwG], Thread[# -> MatrixForm /@ #] & @ vAwGOptns, 
  FrameMargins -> 15]
```

[image]